# uWSGI + Gevent not receiving requests from Nginx

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, uwsgi, gevent, flask-socketio

I'm new to uWSGI/gevent and I have a Python Flask Server with Flask-SocketIo sitting behind Nginx, and the server appears to freeze whenever gevent's loop engine runs. A sample output is shown below:

```
compiled with version: 7.5.0 on 15 April 2020 12:57:22
os: Linux-4.15.0-96-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 1 03:25:46 UTC 2020
nodename: xxxxxxxxxx
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/admin/myapplication
detected binary path: /home/admin/myapplication/venv/bin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 3838
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
- async cores set to 1000 - fd table size: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address connect.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)  [GCC 8.3.0]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55701b9d6e40
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 21036928 bytes (20543 KB) for 1000 cores
*** Operational MODE: async ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x55701b9d6e40 pid: 2692 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 2692)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 2710, cores: 1000)
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x557019f92410] ***
```

At this point, the program produces no further output, despite me attempting to access the page (where I get an Error 502 Bad Gateway).

The app is run via a service file, and it appears to work fine when I run the app directly from the command line. Can anyone identify the issue in my code? (Thanks in advance)

Here is a copy of my service files:

connect.service

```
[Unit]
Description= xxxxxxxxxxxx
After=network.target

[Service]
User=admin
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/admin/myapplication
Environment="PATH=/home/admin/myapplication/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/admin/myapplication/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini service_files/connect.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

connect.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
gevent = 1000
http-websockets = true

socket = connect.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
logto = /home/admin/myapplication/service_files/logs/uwsgi/%n.log

die-on-term = true
```

Nginx site

```
server {

listen 80;

server_name subdomain.domain.com;

return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}

server {

listen 443 ssl;

ssl_certificate /home/admin/myapplication/service_files/connect.crt;

ssl_certificate_key /home/admin/myapplication/service_files/connect.key;

server_name subdomain.domain.com;

location / {

include uwsgi_params;
uwsgi_pass unix:///home/admin/myapplication/connect.sock;

}

location /socket.io/ {

proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
include uwsgi_params;
uwsgi_pass unix:///home/admin/myapplication/connect.sock;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to a permission error (after more digging using the command `sudo tail -30 /var/log/nginx/error.log`)

Going to the connect.ini file and changing `chmod-socket = 660` to `chmod-socket = 666` solved the problem.